# Contact Form 7 submit failed validation

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need Contact Form 7 to send one email when validation has been **failed**. Then send the normal CF7 email when the form is submitted correctly. Ridiculous I know but *clients*!

I think I'm relatively close with the following:

```
function send_failed_vaildation_email( $data ) {
    $messagesend = 'Name:' . $_POST['your-name']; 
    $messagesend .= '\r\nEmail:' .$_POST['email']; 
    $messagesend .= '\r\nPhone:' .$_POST['validPhone']; 
    $messagesend .= '\r\nRate:' .$_POST['rate']; 
    $messagesend .= '\r\nBased:' .$_POST['based']; 
    wp_mail('c******y@gmail.com', 'failed validation mail', $messagesend );
}
add_filter("wpcf7_posted_data", "send_failed_vaildation_email");
```

However this sends all submissions regardless if they pass or fail the validation.

`wpcf7_before_send_mail` is no good as it only fires once the submission passes validation.

I'm either looking for a different hook to use instead of `wpcf7_posted_data` that only fires when validation is failed or an if statement I can place around `wp_mail` for the same effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is one of the weirdest project requirements I have heard in a while...

Comment: @rnevius YUP! I couldn't really believe what they were asking, but they have (what they believe to be) a valid reason to catch the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it working.

@rnevius answer was failing because the `wpcf7_posted_data` filter is applied before the data is validated so nothing is invalid at that time.

Combining @rnevius' answer with the `wpcf7_submit` filter and it works as expected.

Full code:

```
function send_failed_vaildation_email() {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $invalid_fields = $submission->get_invalid_fields();

    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    if ( !empty( $invalid_fields ) ) {
        $messagesend = 'Name:' . $posted_data['your-name']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nEmail:' . $posted_data['email']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nPhone:' . $posted_data['validPhone']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nRate:'  . $posted_data['rate']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nBased:' . $posted_data['based']; 
        $messagesend .= count($invalid_fields); 
        wp_mail('c*******y@gmail.com', 'failed validation mail', $messagesend );
    }
}
add_filter("wpcf7_submit", "send_failed_vaildation_email");
```

Comment: Make sure you mark this as correct, when you get a chance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't been tested, but I'm pretty sure you're going to need to hook into the [get_invalid_fields()](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/includes/submission.php#L56) instance. Something like:

```
function send_failed_vaildation_email() {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $invalid_fields = $submission->get_invalid_fields();

    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    if ( !empty( $invalid_fields ) ) {
        $messagesend = 'Name:' . $posted_data['your-name']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nEmail:' . $posted_data['email']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nPhone:' . $posted_data['validPhone']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nRate:'  . $posted_data['rate']; 
        $messagesend .= '\r\nBased:' . $posted_data['based']; 
        wp_mail('c******y@gmail.com', 'failed validation mail', $messagesend );
    }
}
add_filter("wpcf7_posted_data", "send_failed_vaildation_email");
```

You can see the form submission process [in the plugin trac](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/includes/submission.php).

**EDIT:** I also just noticed the `'wpcf7_validation_error'` hook in [contact-form.php](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/trunk/includes/contact-form.php#L452)...That may be all you need, as it only fires when there's an error.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, unfortunately neither method works... the `get_invalid_fields()` method causes the form to hang on submit - no validation/send takes place. `wpcf7_validation_error` allows the form to validate but no email is sent.

Comment: When you tried the second method, did you use it with your original code? Or my changes above? You should also try to just send a test `wp_mail()` with test content, within `wpcf7_validation_error`. Another thing...CF7 validates via JS, as well as PHP...

Comment: Sorry only just got back round to investigating this. For the `wpcf7_validation_error` method I used my original code with no joy. I then tried it with your changed code and it still didn't work, which I knew it wouldn't. As you suggested also tested it with a test `wp_mail()`, again with no luck (can you see a pattern!). I'm avoiding doing it via JS as I think the client is going to ask to have the data pumped into a database once they start receiving countless rubbish emails. Ho hum, I feel we're getting close, am gonna keep playing around and will report back anything I find.

Comment: I've got closer to finding the problem - `$submission->get_invalid_fields()` always returns 0 even if there are invalid fields which obviously means the `if ( !empty( $invalid_fields ) )` statement isn't triggering. I've reached out to CF7 dev on the WP forums to see if he can help out.

Comment: And the validation isn't happening via JS?

Comment: The validation is taking place as it should (displaying not valid tips, adding class to fields etc...) but for whatever reason `get_invalid_fields()` is returning an empty array!

Comment: I get that...but are you sure the validation isn't happening via JS? Is the `POST`ed data even making it to the server? Or is CF7's JavaScript validator handling the validation before it even gets to the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72413/discussion-between-charliek-and-rnevius).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED CODE FOR LATEST CONTACT FORM 7**

```
function is_gmail($email) {  
if(substr($email, -10) == '@gmail.com') {  
   return true;  
} else {  
   return false;  
};  
};  

function custom_email_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );
if ( 'your-email' == $tag->name ) {
    $the_value = isset( $_POST['your-email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email'] ) : '';
    if(!is_gmail($the_value)){  
             $result->invalidate( $tag, "Are you sure this is the correct address?" );
   };  
 };  
 return $result;  
};  


add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email','custom_email_validation_filter', 20, 2); // Email field  
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_validation_filter', 20, 2); // Required Em
```